# How do I pass request data into the Complete event in JQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to write code to send a jquery AJAX POST request and I'm having some trouble emulating some examples I see.

I want to send a post request to a third party website, and then call a function that would write the responseText to a div, pretty basic stuff.

```
function addSearch(searchTerm) {
    $.ajax({
        accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        url: "http://www.website.com",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        beforeSend : function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("AcceptLanguage", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("AcceptEncoding", "gzip, deflate");
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: createBody(searchTerm),
        complete: doStuffOnComplete(xhr, status)
    });
}

function doStuffOnComplete(xhr, status) {
    var response = xhr.responseText;
    $("#content").append(response);
}
```

I'm following some other basic examples I've seen on here. While I get no errors about the 'xhr' variable in the beforeSend event, I am getting an error in Complete when the script is called, saying xhr is undefined.

I'm sure I'm just messing up something simple, but not having much experience with Jquery, Ajax, or javascript in general I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you're having a problem with the fact the url is a third party.

Try adding `dataType: 'jsonp'` after `type: "POST"`.

Also, rather than using 'complete', I would use 'success' and 'error':

```
[...]
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: createBody(searchTerm),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    error: function(data) {
        console.error(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun PSA for anyone who comes across this later. Turns out this particular bit is impossible! `POST` requests cannot be made to external domains, because it violates the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). `GET` requests can be made to external domains using `JSONP` but sadly there is no way to do this via POST from the client.

The best workaround I've seen discussed (other than using a `JSONP GET` request, which in my case isn't possible) is sending the `POST` request to your own server which in turn sends the request to the external domain.